# I want to know how to create a order create webhook in shopify?

Tags: node.js, shopify-app

I am new to shopify. I am building a shopify app. Now I want to create a webhook in my app which is order create webhook but I am unable to do it. I read shopify documentation but I didn't understant where to begin.

I don't know how to make a endpoint. If I have some example code I think I will understand. I am using node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, I found myself in the same position as you recently. The workshops seem to be out of date given the current file structure that is received when you run NPM init @Shopify/app@latest.

The fix for this is to use the node-express template by passing the template flag into your npm init to specify that you want to use node-express and not hydrogen.